# How to retrieve text from a div on button press in Vue Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I have a list of user details inside a scroll view with each having a button. It looks something like as follows:

1. User 1
2. User 2
3. User 3

The list is rendered using a v-for. On button pressed in each of the divs, I would like to extract some information, such as the User number. How can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vue native you can simply do it this way

```
<view v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
<button :on-press="()=> getDetail(user.number)" />
</view>
```

Then in your script

```
<scripts>
...
methods: {
getDetail(id){
this.number = id // assuming you already have this.number set in your data object
console.log(id)

}

}
<scripts />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with Vuejs3, but you should learn more:

```
<template>

<ul>
    <li v-for="user in users"
        :key="user.id"
        @click="showDetail(user)"
    >
      {{ user.id }} - {{ user.name }}
    </li>
</ul>

<div v-if="clickedUser">
    <h6>Detail</h6>
  <span>{{ clickedUser.id }}</span>
    <span>{{ clickedUser.name }}</span>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
    setup() {
        const users = [
            {id: 1, name: "A"},
            {id: 2, name: "B"},
            {id: 3, name: "C"},
            {id: 4, name: "D"},
        ];
        let clickedUser = ref(null);

        const showDetail = (user) => {
            clickedUser.value = user;
        };

        return {users, clickedUser, showDetail};
    },
};
```